# Update Modelica standard Library in Dymola in Linux

Tags: linux, modelica, dymola

I am using Dymola in Linux. Recently I find I need to update the Modelica standard library from 3.2 to 3.2.1(Got from github).

Anyone knows what I need to set up such that Dymola starts with Modelica 3.2.1?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Dymola 2014 FD01 comes with Modelica 3.2.1 as the default Modelica library.

Comment: It is not available on Internet, isn't it?